# Как в tkinter изменить цвет окна с помощью радиокнопками?

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobutton

В tkinter я создал программа который при нажатии на радиокнопка должен изменится цвет окна. Но не знаю как? Здесь я оставлю код программа:

```
from tkinter import*
def change_color():
    root=Toplevel()
    root.geometry('600x400')
    root.title('Измените цвет окна')
    var=IntVar()
    var.set(1)
    rad0 = Radiobutton(root,text="Красный", variable=var,value=0).grid(row=1, column=1)
    rad1 = Radiobutton(root,text="Синий", variable=var,value=1).grid(row=2, column=1)
    rad2 = Radiobutton(root,text="Зелёный", variable=var,value=2).grid(row=3, column=1)
    lab_color=Label(root, text='Добавьте HEX код цвета: ', font='Times 24')
    lab_color.grid(row=1, column=3)
    color=Entry(root, width=50, bd=3)
    color.grid(row=2, column=3)

root=Tk()
root.title('Enter a color')
root.geometry('600x400')
root['background']= None #Вот здесь должен применить один из цветов вышеуказанного функция

menubar=Menu(root)
filemenu=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label='Измените цвет окна', command=change_color)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*
def change_color():
    root=Toplevel()
    root.geometry('600x400')
    root.title('Измените цвет окна')
    var=IntVar()
    var.set(1)
    rad0 = Radiobutton(root,text="Красный", variable=var,value=0, command = red).grid(row=1, column=1)
    rad1 = Radiobutton(root,text="Синий", variable=var,value=1, command = blue).grid(row=2, column=1)
    rad2 = Radiobutton(root,text="Зелёный", variable=var,value=2, command = green).grid(row=3, column=1)
    lab_color=Label(root, text='Добавьте HEX код цвета: ', font='Times 24')
    lab_color.grid(row=1, column=3)
    color=Entry(root, width=50, bd=3)
    color.grid(row=2, column=3)

def red():
    root['background']= '#F00'

def blue():
    root['background'] = '#002AFF'

def green():
    root['background'] = '#55DE00'

root=Tk()
root.title('Enter a color')
root.geometry('600x400')
root['background']= None #Вот здесь должен применить один из цветов вышеуказанного функция

menubar=Menu(root)
filemenu=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label='Измените цвет окна', command=change_color)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```